# how to use filter in javascript for an array of arrays object?

Tags: javascript

Currently I have an array with values:

```
var array1 = ['new_user', 'promotion']
```

What i need to do is filter and an object with this array1:

```
OBJc = [
    {"id": 1, "array_": ['promotion', 'test1']},
    {"id": 2, "array_": ['test444', 'test1']},
    {"id": 3, "array_": ['new_user', 'test1']}
]
```

I need to filter this json based of if "array_" has any of the values in array1.

So the output would be:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "array_": ['promotion', 'test1']},
    {"id": 3, "array_": ['new_user', 'test1']}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem so far? What error did you get?

Comment: Use a fiddle with your code

Answer (score 1):

You want to filter, so lets filter.

```
OBJc.filter()
```

Now, you want to return true when your property has some value right?

```
OBJc.filter(value => {
  return value['array_'].includes(x)
})
```

But there are multiple ones, and you need to know if at least *some* those values are on your list

```
OBJc.filter(value => {
  return array1.some(arrV => value['array_'].includes(arrV));
})
```

Or if you like one liners:

```
OBJc.filter(value => array1.some(arrV => value['array_'].includes(arrV)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const filtered = OBJc.filter(obj => obj.array_.some(array1.includes))
```

Or with es6 destructuring:

```
const filtered = OBJc.filter({ array_ } => array_.some(array1.includes))
```

Basically you check each array_ element to see if it's included in array 1, and keep only those who satisfy this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```js
var array1 = ['new_user', 'promotion']

JSONstr = [
    {"id": 1, "array_": ['promotion', 'test1']},
    {"id": 2, "array_": ['test444', 'test1']},
    {"id": 3, "array_": ['new_user', 'test1']}
]

const result = JSONstr.filter(obj => {
    let found = false;
    array1.forEach(elm => {
        if (obj.array_.includes(elm)) {
            found = true;
        }
    });
    if (found) {
        return true;
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way if you like playing with booleans.

```
const reduceTruth = (a, b) => a || b;

const matches = JSONstr.filter(element => {
    return element.array_.map( x => array1.map(y => y == x).reduce(reduceTruth, false)).reduce(reduceTruth, false);
});
```